# Protege: Object property restrictions 2

Tags: owl, protege

I'm using Protege 4.3 to create my first ontology, so I encountered a few problems

let's say we have the classes `Person` and `Department` and the properties  `employs` and `hasPart`

So the problem is: I defined some classes like `BigShop`as Equivalent To `employs min 6 Person` and `hasPart some Department` but when I activate the reasoner I don't get the results I'm waiting for, I also tried SubClass Of with the same two restrictions but nothing happened

Any idea why?

Comment: What are you looking for that you didn't find?

Comment: well, I added an individual which satisfies these two restrictions and it was supposed to be asserted in the `BigShop` class after activating the reasoner, but it did not

Comment: I defined the same thing and it classifies it correctly

Comment: that's what's driving me crazy, a lot of the logical results which I'm waiting for dose not happen and I can't tell what is the problem

Comment: @DanaJomer Please show a minimal example (and include the ontology that we can download and load into Protege) where you expect a result that isn't produced.  Otherwise, we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: When you say that something satisfies "employs min 6 Person",  did you actually assert that the persons are distinct?  It's not enough to say employs(x,a) and employs(x,b) in order to infer that "x ∈ employs min 2";  you'd also need to know that a ≠ b.

Comment: actually I did make them distinct and got the same results.

I'm not sure how I can include a part of the ontology here

Comment: by the way I tried to start from the beginning with a simpler ontology about newspapers and their employees and departments and the same thing happened when I defined the classes using object property restrictions.

Comment: Post the ontology source as code in the question, just like any other code.  If you can reproduce the problem in a small ontology, then it should be small enough to post in the question.